# Wrong position of PopupWindow inside RecyclerView after notifyItemChanged

Tags: android, kotlin

I have RecyclerView inside another RecyclerView. When item of inner RecyclerView is clicked, I'm showing PopupWindow like below.
 [image]

When user would click button inside popup, item of outer RecyclerView should update data. The problem is that, after update outer item `notifyItemChanged(position)`, PopupWindow displays in left, top corner of fragment, instead of below item of inner RecyclerView.

[image]

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder : MessageItemHolder, messagePosition : Int)
{
    val item = messages[messagePosition]
    //Display some data

    if(item.isRateViewOpened)
      showRatePopup(holder, messagePosition, item)

    holder.tvMessage.setOnLongClickListener {
        showRatePopup(holder, messagePosition, item)
        true

    }
}

private fun showRatePopup(holder : MessageItemHolder, messagePosition : Int, message : Message)
{
    messages[messagePosition].isRateViewOpened = true
    val rateView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_rate, null)

    setRateIcons(message.status, rateView)

    rateView.ibLike.setOnClickListener { displayRateStatus(RateStatus.LIKE, message, messagePosition, rateView) }
    rateView.ibDislike.setOnClickListener { displayRateStatus(RateStatus.DISLIKE, message, messagePosition, rateView) }

    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(rateView, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true)

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable())
    popupWindow.isOutsideTouchable = true
    val location = IntArray(2)
    holder.tvMessage.getLocationOnScreen(location)
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(holder.tvMessage, 0, 0, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY)
    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener {
        messages[messagePosition].isRateViewOpened = false
    }
}
```